# Transport equation $u_t + xu_x + u = 0$ with $u(x_0, 0) = \cos(x_0)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I have been studying PDEs using Peter Olver's textbook. I have learnt how to solve equations such as $u_t + 2u_x = \sin(x)$ subject to an initial condition such as $u(0,x) = \sin x$. Letting $\epsilon = x - 2t$ and $u(t,x) = v(t,\epsilon)$, I then plug this into the transport equation.

However, I am not sure how to define a characteristic to solve the following equation

$$u_t + xu_x + u = 0, \qquad u(x_0, 0) = \cos(x_0)$$

because it has a variable 'speed' term $x$ and it is also not homogenous because of the term $u$.

A solution would be very helpful so I can see how to approach these problems.

Comment: If you change coordinates to $x = e^y$ then $u_y = xu_x$ so your PDE in these new coordinates simplifies to $u_t + 2u_y + u = 0$. You can even simplify it further by taking $v = e^{t} u$ then $v_t + 2v_y = 0$ which is the equation you say you already know how to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$u_t + xu_x = -u$$
$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{-u}$

First characteristics, from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x}$ :

$$x\,e^{-t}=c_1$$

Second characteristics, from $\quad\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{-u}$ :
$$x\,u=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE : $\quad x\,u=F(x\,e^{-t})$

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}F(x\,e^{-t})$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary condition.

Condition : $\quad u(x_0, 0) = \cos(x_0)=\frac{1}{x_0}F(x_0\,e^{0})$

$F(x_0)=x_0\cos(x_0)$. Now the function $F$ is determined, i.e.: $F(X)=X\cos(X)$.

We put it into the above general solution , where $X=x\,e^{-t}$ , thus $F(x\,e^{-t})=(x\,e^{-t})\cos(x\,e^{-t})$ :

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{x}(x\,e^{-t})\cos(x\,e^{-t})=e^{-t}\cos(x\,e^{-t})$$

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you explain how you obtain your general solution of the PDE from the two characteristics?

Comment: The general solution can be expressed on various forms. For example on the form of implicit equation : $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$, or $c_1=f(c_2)$ or $c_2=F(c_1)$ or other forms. All functions introduced are arbitrary, but they are related one to the other. Doesn't matter the form chosen, the final result is the same after applying the boundary condition.

Comment: Ok I am still not sure how you obtain $xu = F(xe^{-t})$ from your characteristics, I.e. how it depends on $xe^{-t}$?

Comment: $c_2=F(c_1)$ with $c_2=xu$ and $c_1=xe^{-t}$ gives $xu=F(xe^{-t})$.

Comment: Why do you know one constant is a function of the other?

Comment: The function is there in order to express a relationship between the constants. If you don't catch it, you have to come back to the basis of the theory of the method of characteristics.

Comment: Yep I don’t understand the basics. Every textbook does something different!

Answer (score 3):

Let us apply the method of [characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). We get the characteristic equations
$$
\frac{\text{d} t}{\text{d} s} = 1 \, , \qquad
\frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} s} = x \, , \qquad
\frac{\text{d} u}{\text{d} s} = -u \, .
$$
Letting $t(0) = 0$, we know $t=s$. Letting $x(0) = x_0$, we get $x(t) = x_0\, e^t$. Since $u(0) = \cos(x_0)$, we have $u(t) = \cos(x_0)\, e^{-t}$. Finally,
$$
u(x,t) = \cos(x\, e^{-t})\, e^{-t} \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}u(e^t,t+t_0)&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(e^t,t+t_0)+e^t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(e^t,t+t_0)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)(e^t,t+t_0)\\
&=-u(e^t,t+t_0)
\end{align}
holds for all $t$ and $t_0$. Thus
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}u(e^t,t+t_0)+u(e^t,t+t_0)=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left(e^tu(e^t,t+t_0)\right)=0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
e^tu(e^t,t+t_0)=e^{-t_0}u(e^{-t_0},-t_0+t_0)=e^{-t_0}u(e^{-t_0},0)=e^{-t_0}\cos e^{-t_0},
$$
or equivalently,
$$
u(e^t,t+t_0)=e^{-t-t_0}\cos e^{-t_0}.
$$
Finally, let $x=e^t>0$ and $\tau=t+t_0$. This gives $t=\log x$ and $t_0=\tau-\log x$. Hence
$$
u(x,\tau)=e^{-\log x-\tau+\log x}\cos e^{-\tau+\log x}=e^{-\tau}\cos\left(e^{-\tau}x\right).
$$